# jQuery .load() troubles

Tags: jquery, html

I'm messing around with the wonderful world of jQuery (since I eventually want to make good web apps/games) and I got to the .load and .get topics. I saw (here and some other places) that you can insert a page's html into a div if so desired. [I attempted this on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ccQ8A/) but the results were what they are supposed to be. What am I doing wrong?

```
<button id="btn1" type="button">Click!</button>
<div id="box1" style="width: 100px; height:100px"></div>
<div id="box2" style="width: 100px; height:100px"></div>
```

and

```
$('#btn1').click(function () {
    $('#box1').load('http://stackoverflow.com');
    $('#box2').load('http://stackoverflow.com');
});
```

I tried the same code in a bunch of different browsers but still no luck. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you can't `.load` something from a different origin unless both the client and the cross-origin server supports CORS. Try using a local file instead.

Comment: You can load them in an IFrame though

Comment: yeah I already do that, but I wanted to see if this was possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this due to the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

You can't load data from domains outside of the calling script